# MVC Core Dependency Injection: Interface-Repository Generic Parameter Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository

I have read through many books and articles on stackoverflow.
Still receiving error below. Here is my basic outline for Interface, Repository with Generic Parameter. I have AddTransient in my Startup.cs.

In the controller, I am trying to refer to the Interface, without referring to the Repository name. I had the thing working without Generic Parameter. As soon as I implemented Generic Parameter, I receive error below. I want to refer to Interface without referring to Repository or the Model, since we may go from RelationalDB to MongoDB later, etc. How do I get rid of this error?

**Interface:**

```
public interface IProductRepository<T>: IDisposable where T:class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetProductDetail();
```

**Repository:**

```
public class ProductRepository: IProductRepository<ProductdbData>
{
     IEnumerable<ProductdbData> GetProductDetail();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IProductRepository<>), typeof(ProductRepository));
```

**Controller Webpage Error:**

```
namespace CompanyWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController: Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository _productwebrepository; // this line gives error
```

**Error Message: 
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'IProductRepository' requires 1 type arguments**

Comment: The error is very clearly telling you to provide a type parameter.  You don't have an `IProductRepository` interface, you have `IProductRepository<T>`.

Comment: so I should have a generic class for <ProductdbData>? Maybe like generic Productgeneraldata? and ProductDbData would inherit from this? apologize, I started programming 3 months ago, trying to learn from all this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The error message

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. There is a missing type parameter. Just add it :)
Furthermore the provided error code CS0305 is a perfect candidate for googling/binging around.

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0305) states the following:

> This error occurs when the expected number of type arguments was not found. To resolve C0305, use the required number of type arguments.

### Possible solutions

There are multiple ways to solve the problem.

#### 1. Removing the generic parameter

If you are planning to provide just one product type skip the generic parameter entirely and the error will disappear. Additionally you remove unneccessary complexity.

Interace

```
public interface IProductRepository: IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<ProductdbData> GetProductDetail();
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

Controller:

```
namespace CompanyWeb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository _ProductRepository;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _ProductRepository = productRepository;
        }
```

#### 2. Keeping the generic parameter

If you decide to stick to the generic parameter, you actually have to fix the controller and the interface and pass your generic type parameter in both places.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IProductRepository<ProductdbData>, ProductRepository>();
```

Controller:

```
namespace CompanyWeb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository<ProductdbData> _ProductRepository;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository<ProductdbData> productRepository)
        {
            _ProductRepository = productRepository;
        }
```